# table is breaking to late and begins to early on following page

Tags: ruby, prawn

Im using prawn to generate a report basing on a set of data which is displayed in a table. This works perfectly as long as I dont have too much data. When I have more than 20 datasets the table reaches into my page footer and on the following page it begins in the page header.

The best would be to define a kind of area for each page in which the table is displayed. I didnt find any solution by searching the manual. Is there a workaround or sth. like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solition was using a `bounding_box` for the whole document content so it doesnt get involved in the footer or header even not after a page break.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (without knowing too much detail of your use-case):

If the rows are a fixed height, you could just group the data into as many rows as will fit on a page. then insert a page break and draw a new table. refer to http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000833

eg: (in haml)

```
- @people.in_groups_of(5,false) do |people|
  %ul
    - people.each do |person|
      %li= person.name
  %hr
```

that would create multiple `<ul>`'s with up to 5 `<li>` tags in each, separated by a `<hr />`

Hope that applies to your use case somehow.